# More than one data modal for a same database table

Tags: cakephp

I have a table in mydatabase. I want to create two data modals. Is it possible in cakephp?

Additional Information

There is a Table for users. User may be a teacher or a student.
If user is Teacher there is different modal and for student there is also a different data modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CakePHP2

```
class Teacher extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'users';
}
```

But you should be using relationships to distinguish your different user types, you can do this by simply having the Users table with the core information, then create a UserType table linked to specify the type, i.e.

> **Users Table**
>
> id, user_type_id, username, password, created, modified
>
> 1, ***1***, Stephen, somehash, 2015-04-15 00:00:00, 2015-04-15
>   00:00:00
>
> 2, ***2***, Alex, somehash, 2015-04-15 00:00:00, 2015-04-15 00:00:00
>
> 3, ***2***, Jane, somehash, 2015-04-15 00:00:00, 2015-04-15 00:00:00
>
> **UserType Table**
>
> id, name, created, modified
>
> ***1***, Teacher, 2015-04-15 00:00:00, 2015-04-15 00:00:00
>
> ***2***, Student, 2015-04-15 00:00:00, 2015-04-15 00:00:00

Looking at the above data example, you will be able to see that Stephen is a Teacher, Alex is a Student and Jane is a Student.

This keeps it central, you won't need to write model methods in more than one place, these links have more info on relationships.

CakePHP2: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

CakePHP3: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can create different models using the same table name. To do so, link each model with specific table with $useTable property (not $table):

```
class Teacher extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'User';
}
```

Find more detailed solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967556/cakephp-multiple-models-for-one-table) and [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878227/how-do-mysql-views-work)

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP2, you can use the `$useTable` attribute of a model to set the table to be used:

```
class Example extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'exmp'; // This model uses a database table 'exmp'
}
```

It looks like it might need to be done differently in CakePHP 3 (or v3 adds a different way of doing it) (see [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro.html#the-model-layer))

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

$users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
$user = $users->newEntity(['email' => 'mark@example.com']);
$users->save($user);
```