# Can a view select statement contain another view?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to refer a views column as a select statement for another view?

How about joining two views together in another view?

How can I refer to a view column. I have used GROUP_CONCAT(column1) in the initial view but then couldnt refer to it later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes it is possible. For reference go through [MySql Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)

but note that nesting views can cause serious performance penalties.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Without more detail, that's about as descriptive as I can be.

[BTW, I think this is something you could have found easily by searching.]

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about nesting views - often you will find that nesting views many levels deep without keeping an eye on indexes and the query plan can end up with a massive spider-like plan which absolutely kills the server.

My favourite ever query plan was one from a consultant where I work that had used views upon views.... ouch

Comment: +1. I've seen those so deep: down the rabbit hole!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use almost any object you can use when running a simple `SELECT` statement (view among them).

You can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878227/how-do-mysql-views-work) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Yes and yes, however, keep an eye on performance. Also read the documentation on create view, there are number of things that go iffy on you, for instance if both views have limit clauses, which one gets used is indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

For select statements, views *are* the same as tables.

Actually, I routinely nest views, often many levels deep.