# What is MySQL View for?

Tags: mysql

[MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) explains how to create a view. However it doesn't explain why should I make a MySQL View in the first place.

Thus, my question is, what is MySQL View? What is it for? At what circumstances should I make or not make one?

Quoting the documentation

> The view definition is “frozen” at creation time and is not affected by subsequent changes to the definitions of the underlying tables.

I don't see how creating a view would be beneficial, so please, enlighten me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do MySQL views work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878227/how-do-mysql-views-work)

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/introduction-sql-views.aspx

Comment: IMO Views in MySQL are of limited use, because they cannot use indexes. That said, it can occasionally be easier to manipulate a single view, rather than each of its underlying tables.

Answer (score 1):

1. View the data without storing the data into the object.
2. Restrict the view of a table i.e. can hide some of columns in the tables.
3. Join two or more tables and show it as one object to user.
4. Restrict the access of a table so that nobody can insert the rows into the table.

Answer (score -1):

Where I work, we use the views as big painful querys that we need many times,  we decided to create views for them instead of doing a manual query and when we need to access the information

```
SELECT * FROM view WHERE (anything)
```

Comment: How does that answer the question?